# What is 91/100 CV when referring to olives?

Tags: shopping, olive

I often see numbers like 91/100 CV when buying olives.

Example: [GREEN OLIVE MACARICO GORDAL 91/100 CV 500G](https://delicias-uk.com/en/inicio/6555-green-olive-macarico-91100-cv-500g)

What do these numbers mean? I tried to do some research and I think it might have to do with the size of the olives, but I still cannot figure out what they mean exactly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CV is a common abbreviation for *cultivar* ([ALLACRONYMS](https://www.allacronyms.com/cultivar/abbreviated) q.v. and used, e.g., in [here (pdf)](http://hera.ugr.es/doi/15058025.pdf) and [here](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/journal-of-nutritional-science/article/table-olives-and-health-a-review/A1598E4986C34D96878EAAB8388BBC1B#)).  The Gordal olive weighs about [12](https://en.excelentesprecios.com/gordal-olives) grams (search for "size").

Assuming they are pitted, and allowing for pit weight of about one to two grams, would indicate about 90 to 100 olives per kilogram as suggested by AMTwo.

(Note that [Macarico](https://www.macarico.pt/en/variedade-de-azeitona) states an average weight of 12.5 grams for the Gordal olive.)

Answer (score 3):

Olives are sized by "number of olives per kilogram" (or per pound, in the US). In this case the packaging is 500 grams, so I'd assume we're talking olives per kilo here.

91/100 olives mean that it will take between 91 and 100 olives in a kilo. There are additional requirements to ensure consistent sizing, so that there isn't a mix of golf balls and tiny olives in a given container.

Comment: What does CV stand for? Also any idea why they use a "/" instead of "-" which would have been more logical to represent a range?